# Add elements to nested elements using JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

```
I have a document structure that looks similar to this:

<article id="post1" class="post-5 page type-page" > 
   <section class = "holder clearfix">

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">
        </a>
     </div>

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">
        </a>
     </div>

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">
        </a>
     </div>

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">
        </a>
     </div>


 </section>
</article>
```

What I want to do is add a div with a class and a unique ID to each **a** element using JQuery.

The end result would look something like this

```
<article id="post1" class="post-5 page type-page" > 
   <section class = "holder clearfix">

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">

           <div id="button1" class = "shiny-button"> </div>     // unique ID
        </a>
     </div>

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">

            <div id="button2" class = "shiny-button"> </div>     // unique ID
        </a>
     </div>

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">
            <div id="button3" class = "shiny-button"> </div>     // unique ID
        </a>
     </div>

     <div class = "four columns">
      <a title class = "single-image short-link" href "http://whatever.com" target = "self">     
          <div id="button4" class = "shiny-button"> </div>     // unique ID
        </a>
     </div>


 </section>
</article>
```

So far the following JQuery code gets me about half way there:

```
$('<div/>', {
    class:'shiny-button',
}).appendTo('.single-image');
```

I tried playing with code that looks similar to the following but I can't seem to get it right

```
$('<div/>', {
    class:'shiny-button',
    id: 'button1',
}).appendTo('.holder .four:nth-child(1)');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using each. So

```
$('.single-image').each(function(index){
    //Append new element to $(this)
    //index will be a counter
    //$(this) = the current $('.single-image') element
});
```

I believe you can use the index to be unique. i can't remember but the `.each()` function is documented in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#post1 .single-image').append(function(i){
    return '<div id="button'+(i+1)+'" class = "shiny-button"> dd</div>'
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pJ86b/)